# What type of throw is the Laats' Dive-In?

Tags: judo, technique, throwing

The "[Laats' Dive-in](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ebmp_Xa82ZM&feature=youtu.be&t=36s)" (named after its use by Johan Laats) is often described as a variant of kata-guruma avoiding grabbing the leg. However, I have seen some debate as to how the throw should actually be classified, with some instead calling it an uki-waza variant.<sup>[1](https://old.reddit.com/r/judo/comments/2xdni0/new_odd_crazy_throws_video_list/)</sup>

How does the Kodokan classify this throw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Kodokan Judo Nage Waza - Various techniques and their names* in its section on sutemi-waza explicitly describes a throw which starts off in a kata-guruma position but is executed by sacrificing one's balance to the ground as *uki-waza*:

> [image]
>
> This is a technique of following on from kata-guruma to uki-waza. In this technique, **as you are sacrificing yourself and making the throw, it is not kata-guruma.**
>
> - [*Kodokan Judo Nage Waza - Ma-sutemi-waza - Uki-waza*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0q9WKNZMrU&t=548)