# How is "front" uchi-mata (Yagura-nage) classified?

Tags: judo, terminology, throwing, sumo

There is a competition throw in judo which resembles:

- an *uchi-mata* lifting with the front of the thigh, or equivalently
- an *obi-tori-gaeshi* where you continue the turn after lifting (as opposed to reversing uke in the opposite direction).
- an *uki-goshi* with tori lifting their leg off the ground

It [tends to be called](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xox1wWPVTrQ) [*yagura-nage*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vzDCuJMWIuk) in Japan (since this is what the throw is called in [sumo](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%AB%93%E6%8A%95%E3%81%92)), and '[front uchi-mata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sQplsEnXwmg)' in the west. Does the kodokan have a position on how this is classified?

---

I've seen some variants which are effectively an *utsuri-goshi*, but I'm talking about ones with a direct entry lifting and throwing with the same hip.

Comment: For me, it is a form of *ushiro-goshi*. I am not aware of any Kodokan statement though.